# Google Chrome remote debugging not showing anything

Tags: android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

My workplace develops hybrid mobile apps for iOS and Android using the ionic framework.
This means that on-device debugging mostly happens through Chrome's remote debugging feature.

However, I have the following issue when attempting to debug our apps on my phone:
[Screenshot of chrome://inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4w9Y.png)

As you can see, Chrome displays my device, but does not view any of my tabs or WebView instances. This is independent of what chrome version or WebView implementation is currently in use, it just shows **nothing.**

I should mention running/installing etc. apps via ADB works fine and the device is detected. Just chrome remote debugging is completely non-functional.

My Device is Xiaomi Poco X3 running ArrowOS 11.0 (Android R).
Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: This is also happening to me. Not only in chrome. Firefox fails to connect for remote debugging, too. I have a ginkgo phone with ArrowOS 12.0 (Android S)